# Traverse binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

Hi guys i'm having trouble understanding the following homework question.
I have done most of the work, but don't get the sample output expected. This is probably because i have miss understood the way our professor wants us to insert Values. I have given my insert method and sample output. Can you guys see if i'm doing something wrong

Comment: Your first set of input is confusing.  What is your actual input to the program?  The first line is "java A02Q05 4 5 2 7 3 6 8", but what are the other lines?  Are those command line inputs for each type of traversal?  Regardless, your preorder traversals are wrong.  The way all of those potential input values are structured, 6 cannot come before 7 in the preorder traversal (with all of these "inputs" 7 should always be the parent of 6, meaning that 7 will always be encountered before 6 in a preorder traversal).  Make sure you draw the trees and trace the path for each.

Comment: the actual input is 4 5 2 7 3 6 8, i have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

From the sample output given by your professor, it seems that he does not actually intend you to insert the values in any sorted order, but simply build a tree, level-by-level, using the input values.

In other words, the tree he expects from the sample input should look like this:

```
       4
     /   \
  5         2
 /  \      /  \
7    3    6    8
```

If you read this tree from top to bottom, left to right, you get the sample input: `4 5 2 7 3 6 8`.